# How can i add a delete button in my script?

Tags: php

I just want add a delete button that can delete 1 perticular row from database.

The output of my script is like this-:

username   12334
   username1   12334

```
But i want something like this-:
username   12334    delete
username1   12334   delete
```

so that if i click on second rows's delete then i want it removed from the database.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","****");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
$list="select d_name,d_amount from donated order by d_id desc limit 10;";
$data=mysqli_query($con,$list); 
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>" ."<strong>NAME OF DONER(s)</strong>" . "</td><td>" . "<strong>AMOUNT  DONATED</strong>" . "</td></tr>";
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
echo "<tr><td>" . $info['d_name'] . "</td><td>" . $info['d_amount'] . "</td></tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","****");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

if(isset($_GET['delete'])){ // if there is id in current url
    $id = intval($_GET['delete']); // parse it
    mysqli_query($con, 'DELETE FROM donated WHERE d_id = ' . $id); // and remove row from database
}

$list="select d_name,d_amount,d_id from donated order by d_id desc limit 10;"; //added id to select statement
$data=mysqli_query($con,$list); 
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>" ."<strong>NAME OF DONER(s)</strong>" . "</td><td>" . "<strong>AMOUNT  DONATED</strong>" . "</td></tr>";
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
echo "<tr><td>" . $info['d_name'] . "</td><td>" . $info['d_amount'] . "</td><td><a href='?delete=" . $info['d_id'] . "'>delete</a></td></tr>"; // we add delete url here
}   
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your query like this,

```
    <?php
    $list="select d_id,d_name,d_amount from donated order by d_id desc limit 10;";
    $data=mysqli_query($con,$list); 
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>" ."<strong>NAME OF DONER(s)</strong>" . "</td><td>" . "<strong>AMOUNT  DONATED</strong>" . "</td>
    <td> DELETE </td></tr>";
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $info['d_name'] . "</td><td>" . $info['d_amount'] . "</td>";
    ?>
```

Pass your ID here

```
    <td> <a href="<?php echo "your_page.php?action=delete&id=".$info['d_id']; ?>"> delete </a> </td> </tr>

    <?php
    }   
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Now catch your ID at the top of your page & run delete query,

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'delete')
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "delete from donated where d_id = '$id'";
    }
    ?>
```